# Resolve javascript conflict with parent theme on wordpress child theme

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming, buddypress

I've built a child theme of [Divi Theme](http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/) to use with [Buddypress](https://buddypress.org/). So far so good, except for a script conflict on commenting buttons.

The theme load a javascript (`js/custom.js` at 2642:2662) with the following function:

```
    $( 'a[href*=#]:not([href=#])' ).click( function() {
        if ( $(this).closest( '.woocommerce-tabs' ).length && $(this).closest( '.tabs' ).length ) {
            return false;
        }

        if ( location.pathname.replace( /^\//,'' ) == this.pathname.replace( /^\//,'' ) && location.hostname == this.hostname ) {
            var target = $( this.hash );
            target = target.length ? target : $( '[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']' );
            if ( target.length ) {
                et_pb_smooth_scroll( target, false, 800 );

                if ( ! $( '#main-header' ).hasClass( 'et-fixed-header' ) && $( 'body' ).hasClass( 'et_fixed_nav' ) && $( window ).width() > 980 ) {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                        et_pb_smooth_scroll( target, false, 200);
                    }, 500 );
                }

                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

This event target the same button that Buddypress use for commenting, preventing AJAX form from loading on click.

[image]

I don't want to edit the parent theme (custom.js). How can I prevent this conflict? Is there a workaround, maybe from **functions.php**?

**UPDATE**

Using [wp_dequeue_script][4] to load that script later, didn't work. When using this code in functions.php

```
function de_script() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'divi-custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'de_script', 100 );
```

then the full script (custom.js) was not loaded at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to resolve the javascript conflict I've set up a simple `tl_custom.js` under my theme `js/` folder, with the following code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //  Remove handler set by themes/Divi/js/custom.js at line 2642
    $( 'a[href*=#]:not([href=#])' ).off();
});
```

Then I add the script with the following code in `functions.php`

```
function tl_custom_scripts() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $scriptsrc = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/';
        wp_register_script( 'tl_custom', $scriptsrc . 'tl_custom.js', '', '', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'tl_custom' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tl_custom_scripts', 20 );
```

The main problem is that the parent theme register `custom.js` in the footer, so I had to set the [wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) last parameter to `true` and then set [add_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) priority to 20.

Answer (score 0):

this answer may be a bit too late now but I am currently working on an inherited project of which I continued working on. I found that they were using a Divi theme on an updated Wordpress which triggers all the errors above.

I inspected the source error and I found that this selector was incorrect:

```
$( 'a[href*=#]:not([href=#])' )
```

I fixed this by changing it to this without compromising any functionality:

```
$( 'a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#])' )
```

It also works with this:

```
$( 'a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])' )
```

The issue was fixed and the functionality for that block of code is still working.